# Combine MonogDB aggregate function with $in or $nin

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying to query data using MongoDB query which combine $match together with $nin operators:

```
coll = mdb.get_collection_by_name('Client')
query = [
    {"$group": {"_id": {"Domain": "$Domain"}, "count":{"$sum":1}}},
    {"$match": { "UserName": { "$nin": excluded_users}}},
    {"$sort": { "count": -1 } }
]

res = list(coll.aggregate(query))
print(res)
```

As it seems, MongoDB ignores my $match line and calculate records which contains `excluded users` as well. I tried to search for similar examples but didn't find queries which combine $match with $in or $nin. Is that supported?
Am I doing something wrong? What is the best way to combine aggregate queries with $nin or $in operators?
Thanks

Comment: after the first stage "$group" the document will only have _id and count field, but you want to match on UserName field. You might need to move $match before $group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `$group` step removes all fields which are not explicitly stated. That means the documents which arrive in your `$match` stage only have the fields `_id` and `count`. There is no field `UserName` anymore you could match by. If you want to filter by `UserName`, you need to make sure the `UserName`'s are also part of the documents generated by `$group`.

Because `$group` squashes multiple documents into one, you need to specify how to deal if multiple of the grouped documents have different values for `UserName`. Options are `$last`/`$first` to use the value of the last/first aggregated document (warning: without an explicit `$sort` before `$group`, the order is unpredictable), `$addToSet` to create an array of all unique values or `$push` to create an array of all values with duplicates.

But chances are, that you want to filter the documents with the unwanted documents *before* you group them, so a better solution might be to move `$match` before `$group`.